# Unmet dependencies- unable to install python-catkin-pkg

Tags: ubuntu, ros, catkin

I'm trying to install roslaunch but it says I need to install roslib, then that says I need to install catkin, which says I need to install python-catkin-pkg.

I first call `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`
and for each dependency I've tried to install. When it gets to `sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg` it says python-catkin-pkg is already the newest version (0.4.16-000)

So then I try to install catkin with `sudo apt-get install catkin` and the terminal returns the message: >Reading package lists... Done

> Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done
>   Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
>   requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
>   distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
>   or been moved out of Incoming.
>   The following information may help to resolve the situation:
>
> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
>    catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed
>   E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

[Screenshot of error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkaGi.png)

I'm new to ros and just installed ubuntu on a VM, I followed the instructions from ros wiki by creating a catkin workspace and package and from there I made a folder called roslaunch and within it I made an empty file called roslaunch.launch which was the original file I was trying to run. Thank you

Comment: This python-catkin-pkg should work. you dont need to install catkin.

Answer (score -2):

while executing
sudo apt install catkin

it has recommended the following suggestions:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
catkin : Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: But what should we do to fix it? Try offering a proper suggestion.